# Backbone RequireJS and delegateEvents

Tags: backbone.js

In my router I require a view like this:

```
require(['views/business-detail-view'],
    function(BusinessDetailView) {
        var businessDetailView = new BusinessDetailView({collection:                        businessOverviewCollection.models[id], id: id});
        businessDetailView.render();
    }
);
```

and in the view I'm binding events like this:

```
events: {
        'click #about-btn'   : 'aboutHandler',
        'click #contact-btn' : 'contactHandler',
        'click #deals-btn'   : 'dealsHandler',
        'click #map-btn'     : 'mapHandler'
},
```

Now the issue is that if the view gets rendered the first times the callbacks are invoked ones. But if the view needs to be rendered again in some other place the callbacks are invoked twice and so on.

How can I prevent this or am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

In the meantime I have changed the code in my router to:

```
if ( !businessDetailView ) {
    require(['views/business-detail-view'],
        function(BusinessDetailView) {
            businessDetailView = new BusinessDetailView({collection: businessOverviewCollection.models[id]});
            businessDetailView.render(); 
        }
    );
}
else {
    businessDetailView.collection = businessOverviewCollection.models[id];
    businessDetailView.render(); 
}
```

which seem to solve the issue, but I'm still to new to backbone this know whether this is a valid pattern.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "invoked twice". A "normal" rendering does not invoke the callbacks. Please share complete code.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your view you probably clear out the existing HTML on the page and replace it with new HTML. When you clear out old HTML you should also clear out old event handlers so they aren't laying around. For example, in your view when you want to render your newHtml you could do:

```
@$el.off().html(newHtml)
```

Comment: sorry but this seems to unbind the events at all, no callbacks are invoked anymore